# How to stop using the camera, without having to release the Cyclops controls

Tags: subnautica

I've got myself a Cyclops, and because of its size it's pretty hard to see where it's going, or when I'm bumping into walls. Fortunately, it's got a set of cameras mounted on the sub, which I can control from the cockpit.

But I don't know how to stop using the cameras, except by using "e". But hitting "e" also lets go of the control stick itself. Usually, I do actually want to keep steering the ship, I just want to use my own eyes to look out the cockpit...

Is there any way to stop seeing through the cameras, without letting go of the Cyclops' control stick?

Comment: I've found a few forums on Steam discussing this, and it seems the Escape Key or E use to work to exit the cameras and continue steering.  But it seems another update removed this functionality.  So it does sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know which update specifically fixed this issue, but as of the 1.0 release you can right-click to switch back from camera view to normal driving view. I believe you can also press Esc for the same effect.

Comment: My understanding is that right-clicking now in camera mode will turn the external flood lights on and off, and you need to press "E in order to exit the camera mode. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 5):

Update 5/28/2020:
Having just completed the game again (today!) I can say that now there is a way to cancel the camera usage without exiting the piloting controls. Now you can press "E" to exit the camera control, and you need to press "E" again after that in order to step back from piloting the Cyclops. I was glad to see they finally updated this, although I'm not sure which update it was included with, and I don't care enough to search change logs, but it's definitely there as of today.

Original Post:

I've been through every command available in the game settings, and I've not found a way to stop viewing the camera without exiting pilot mode. Whether or not it's an intended feature or a bug, I submitted it as a bug to the developers, because I'd think there should definitely be a way to do so.